# Proof: The space of continuous functions separates distributions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

I try to understand the following lemma:

If $(S,d)$ is a metric space and let $p$,$q$ be two Borel probability measures defined on $S$. Then $p=q$ if and only if $\int f\,\mathrm{d}p = \int f\,\mathrm{d}q$ for all $f \in C_b(S)$ where $C_b(S)$ is the space of continuous bounded functions on $S$.

If I understand this correctly, then $C_b(S)$ separates all probability distributions. The only hint I can find is Lemma 9.3.2 in "Real analysis and probability from Dudley". However I don't see how one can use this to proof the statement above.

Does anyone know a proof for this lemma (maybe in more detail)?

Edit: Lemma 9.3.2 says

> If $(S,d)$ is a metric space, $P$ and $Q$ are two laws on $S$, and $\int f\,\mathrm{d}P = \int f\,\mathrm{d}Q$ for all $f \in C_b(S)$, then $P=Q$.
>
> Proof:
> Let $U$ be any open subset of $S$ with complement $F$ and consider the distance $d(x,F)$ from $F$. For $n=1,2,...$ let $f_n(x) := \min(1,nd(x,F))$. Then $f_n \in C_b(S)$ and as $n\to \infty, f_n \uparrow 1_U$. So by monotone convergence, $P(U) = Q(U)$, so $P(F)=Q(F)$. Then by closed regularity, $P=Q$.

I do not understand in this proof why it is required that the integrals must be equal for all $f \in C_b(S)$. This proof is a little bit too compact for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is composed in two step:

1. If two probability measures agree on the closed sets, then they agree on the Borel sets (by regularity, that is, we approximate by below a Borel set by a closed set).
2. We approximate pointwise the characteristic function of an open set and increasingly in order to use monotone convergence. Indeed, we start from the equality for the approximating continuous bounded function (that is where the assumption of equality of the integrals of continuous bounded functions is used) then use monotone convergence theorem to get it with the characteristic function of the open set.